# position incompatibility with float

Tags: html, css

Position absolute seems to be working different in Firefox and chrome when using float: left.

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

```css
.ulfloat{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ulfloat li{
    float: left;
}
.g-blue{
    background-color: blue;
}

.g-red{
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul class="ulfloat">
        <li>
            <a>
                <i class="g-blue">as</i>
                <span class="g-red">bs</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Using:

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
- Google Chrome 39
- Firefox v34

This is the structure I'm using to create a notification badge and because of this issue my notification looks the following way:

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox ( this is the behaviour I want ):

[image]

- how can I fix it to ensure compatibility between browsers?
- Which is the correct behaviour ?

Comment: Working differently how?

Comment: `position:absolute` is not affected by float ... so if the parent has it or not is the same. What this needs is a relative parent because is off of the flow now, and search for the closest non-static parent to be positioned

Comment: @Paulie_D I just add some pictures

Comment: I see why is different but what are you trying to acomplish? why you use absolute ?

Comment: Google Chrome adds browser styling, to ensure cross browser compatability, reset styles.  Get a copy of the latest version of reset here http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/

Comment: @Danko Does that mean that the correct behaviour is the one of chrome ?

Comment: Both are correct .... now `g-red` is out and positioned relative to the body try setting left and top values and you will see the same result.... the difference here is just on the way the actual position is and how the element is taken out based on browser dependences.

Comment: @Danko sorry, I don't understand why both are correct. If the html and css are the same I would expect the same result in both browsers ( if html and css are compatible)

Comment: This looks like a discrepancy in how browsers handle shrink-to-fit, with relation to absposed children in the static position. This also looks pretty familiar, but I don't recall off the top of my head if I saw this on SO or elsewhere.

Comment: @BoltClock so at the end which is the correct behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `left` / `right` or `top`/ `bottom` that is the main reason we use [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> **absolute** Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to
>   the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins,
>   they do not collapse with any other margins.

**Note:**

You may want to add `position: relative` to the list element since you are using the `position: absolute` on his child.

Here is an alternative:(apply the float on i and span instead of li)

```css
.ulfloat{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ulfloat i, .ulfloat span{
    float: left;
}
.g-blue{
    background-color: blue;
}

.g-red{
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul class="ulfloat">
        <li>
            <a>
                <i class="g-blue">as</i>
                <span class="g-red">bs</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Although the *reason* we use `position: absolute` is so we can position according to those coordinates, it's not absolutely necessary to set them to avoid problems.

Comment: ... or at least, that's what the spec would like to have us believe. Clearly that's not what we're seeing here.

Comment: @BoltClock chrome has its `user agent stylesheet` which adds `display: list-item;` and `text-align: -webkit-match-parent;` to the list element change it and you will have the same result as in firefox.  http://i.imgur.com/WOqMLim.png

Comment: I don't see how those two properties would affect anything. `display: list-item` is the default on all browsers (as it should be), and `text-align` doesn't seem relevant. That said, I tried to change it and it makes no difference either.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing it on my Chrome/Win 39. I really don't understand why Chrome has to have platform inconsistencies, but there you go.

Comment: @Tambo thanks.. that's working for me, could you elaborate more why that did the trick ?